# UX Awareness session in new organisation

Tags: culture, workshop

I have joined a new organisation and I want to conduct a session on creating awareness about User Experience.
Could you suggest me some references, ideas, or workshop that will help the organisation to understand the value of user experience?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, **showing the value of UX in an organization is a marathon, not a sprint.** You can absolutely hold an educational session to introduce UX concepts and talk about its value, including examples of how other organizations like yours reaped a significant return on investment from UX.

But the work merely begins there. Your next step would be to **find some quick and easy ways to make impact** with UX in your organization. What are some pain points that wouldn't take a lot of research and development to solve? Do those projects first - and if you can, get some "before and after" measurements to show how they increased revenue or saved cost.

Once you start earning a reputation for solving problems with UX, you'll (hopefully) start to see more understanding of its value. It takes time, though. Keep measuring the impact as much as you can with real numbers ([here's one framework](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/google-s-heart-framework-for-measuring-ux)), and keep socializing the impact to leaders and stakeholders.

Answer (score 0):

None of these will help if you don't measure the UX maturity at your company first, as each maturity level needs a different approach. In order to make changes, you have to know what is currently there, how you can deal with it, then you can come up with a solution.

I know, I have tried it plenty of times before, I realized the importance of measuring the UX maturity first.

And you may also search for what is the difference between the Tactical and the Strategical UX approaches. At the lower level of UX maturity, tactical is usually more functional and most of all, needed, appreciated. At a higher level, thinking strategical and communicating like a strategist is the right way to find a common voice with stakeholders at a company.